# Paypal after order create

Tags: php, paypal

I try to integrate paypal to mywebsite with this code:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="form_paypal">
    <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxx">
    <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="<?php echo $requestParameters["currency"]; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="order_number" value="<?php echo $order_d_id; ?>">
    <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
   //items
   ......
    <!-- Specify URLs -->
    <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='https://xxx/cart'>
    <input type='hidden' name='return' value='https://xxx/cart'>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("form_paypal").submit();
</script>
```

It work fine, redirect to sandbox and make the payment very well, but i need to get the **order number** because after the payment the order is created and i send it in the form **order_number** but after payment i get only this prams in header :

**`https://xxx/cart?amt=37.00&cc=USD&st=Pending&tx=7CN14150L22664531`**

I need to get order_number to change status,

Thank you for help.

Comment: paypal has some specific field names that if you send it will return, but i cant recall them off hand but should be trivial for you to look up

Comment: You can use PayPal IPN, once the payment completes then PayPal will send a notification with all the information. Refer: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/

Comment: Yes the PAYPAL IPN work's good for me , thank you for help